# How to fix "You must install or update .NET to run this application." error?

Tags: c#, homebrew, dotnet-cli

I am using `brew` to install .NET 6 and 7. My application is running `.NET 6 Core` which I cannot upgrade ATM. So trying to install multiple .NET versions to avoid such issues.

**Brew Commands:**

- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dotnet@6 (for `.NET 6`)
- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dotnet#default (for `.NET 7`)

**Installed versions:**

- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100`
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet@6/6.0.114`
- [image]

Now, when I run `dotnet --info` I see following. As you can see, it is taking `Base Path:   /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100`

[image]

Here, when I try to run a command using `dotnet cli`, I am getting the following message. I think here the issue is, my app is running on  `'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (arm64)` and it is finding  `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/`

[image]

**Questions:**

- How to set the path here where cli can find both .NET versions?
- I think if above is satisfied, then I should see both SDKs while running `dotnet --info`. Is that correct?

**Update:**

- I installed `.NET 6.0 SDK (v6.0.411) - macOS Arm64` from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.411-macos-arm64-installer) but still not seeing that SDK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as ".NET 6 Core"...

Comment: That's a bug in the brew. Microsoft releases [installers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos) and [install scripts](https://github.com/dotnet/install-scripts) for the runtime and SDK, not brews. What you posted shows that .NET 6 wasn't installed, neither the runtime nor the SDK. Download and run the correct installer. The brew's [source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/c37f6edc3a3235311223b05d43b098f751d1dce3/Formula/dotnet@6.rb#L58) shows it's retrieving and running an older install script to bypass a bug that ... was fixed 1 year ago

Comment: Note that DOTNET_ROOT environment variable appears to be set (not sure if that is your app or something else - but it points to the Net 7 install).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I installed SDK from here, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.411-macos-x64-installer but still same thing. I also installed runtime which shows successful installation as well

Comment: What do you get if you run `dotnet --list-sdks` ? Only *one* runtime version can be active in a project. By default, it's the latest one. To use a different version you can use a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) file to specify the .NET version that's used by every folder below the one the file is in.

Comment: Wait - you downloaded the *Intel* (x64) SDK, not the ARM SDK. All the .NET 6 downloads [are here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). You need to download the ARM64 installer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, I realized that after adding the comment and then installed ARM SDK. I see that successfully installed, used [sdk-6.0.411](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.411-macos-arm64-installer) but still seeing only .NET 7 SDK on `dotnet --list-sdks`

Answer (score 2):

It seems the .NET 6 brew has a bug. The image you posted shows that the *x64* version of the SDK was downloaded instead of ARM.
[image: Image showing an x64 SDK installation]

Microsoft releases [installers and install scripts for the runtime and SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) for Mac, not brews. The brew's [source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/c37f6edc3a3235311223b05d43b098f751d1dce3/Formula/dotnet@6.rb#L58) shows it's retrieving and running an older install script to bypass a bug that was [fixed 1 year ago](https://github.com/dotnet/install-scripts/issues/318)

You should download the MacOS ARM64 installer from the [Downloads page for .NET 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0).

After that you'll be able to build applications that target both runtimes. The tool chain used will be the latest though (7.0). Normally, this shouldn't be a problem. If you want to use a *specific* version, you can create a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) at the root of your .NET 6 folder and specify the version you want to be used inside the entire directory tree

Comment: So I installed ARM64 for .NET 6 successfully -> ran `dotnet --list-sdks` -> seeing only .NET 7. Not sure what am I missing here. Updated my question with screen shots.